LVM2 - non-root VG LV not activated on reboot
One of our physical Ubuntu server has,
3 VGs in total - rootvg, 2 non-rootvgs(appvg1 & appvg2).
Rootdisk is local HDD and both appvgs uses multipath disk (one disk each).
appvg1 has filesystem that will mount during boot and appvg2 just has LV that will be mapped to KVM VM.
Ubuntu has both multipath-tools & multipath-tools-boot pkgs installed
On every reboot, all 3 vgs are activated, but appvg2 LV is not activated.
Using default LVM2 Event based activation using pvscan systemd units.
I'm confused why would VG becomes active but not LV (appvg2/lv)
